# Remove all personal data from workplace computers

Tags: privacy

I have given my notice at a small software development firm. I still have a couple of weeks so I am transferring my knowledge to a colleague. A couple of days ago, I have realized that I am not allowed to wipe the hard drives of the two computers I have been using. I have also found out that some of my passwords were stored as plaintext on some local servers. What would be the best course of action for me in order to keep my privacy?

Comment: Change your password?

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing that I thought of but I am wondering if there's anything else to do? I have several personal accounts that might utilize the password I've used and I might forget to change one of them. It's not probable, just looking for another way.

Comment: This is for anyone else who comes across this question. Do not put personal information on your work computer in the first place. I've come back from a long weekend to find my boss had sold my computer to a customer. If you need to do something personal, use your phone and use cellular data.

Comment: I am also genuinely interested in why this question deserves a downvote.

Comment: Work is work. Personal is personal. Never the twain shall meet.

Comment: You may have been downvoted because while the computer involved is at your workplace, this is a question that would be better on Information Security.

Comment: The firm is using Subversion (svn) servers for code management. The funny thing is that the director of the company is calling himself a security freak.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? If it's just a question of what sort of personal data you should store on workplace computers, that's probably fine for this site. But it sounds more like you're wondering about what you should do now, to remove the data and keep yourself safe now that the data is already there. That is a bit too technical and security related for this site and would fit better on [security.se] (at least the part about keeping yourself safe, how to remove the data may be hard to answer without knowing way too much about your setup). Also, what data exactly? Just passwords?

Comment: @Dukeling I am asking what measures should I take to delete the personal data from the workplace computers. I believe those measures can be both technical and people-related, which is why I have posted it here. Also, people have given advice about what should be even stored on the workplace computers to begin with. Also, yes, just the passwords concern me since I used one that is almost the same as some of my personal passwords. I have never used my work computers for personal tasks except in some light manner (for example, looking for a phone in a web store).

Comment: I have asked a colleague that handles work accounts (the firm is small and structured in a manner that most of us have more jurisdiction than just software development) about what else is stored as plain text and how securely the passwords are changed, i.e. if the history is easily accessed.

Comment: Noone is supposed to have the time to look for deleted data on PCs of colleagues that moved on and restore it just for fun.

Comment: To wrap this up, I do not know what else I expected but I got sensible advice from you all: delete every piece of private information in the most secure manner I can and do not ever store personal information of any kind on a workplace pc. I thought it harmless but, now I'm leaving, it's better to be safe than sorry. Thanks!

Comment: NMilev, And don't reuse the same password pattern (That's probably why your question got downvoted. Not that I downvoted you, but someone else did). Chances are. Some of your existing passwords have probably already been compromised. https://haveibeenpwned.com/ Use hard passwords and use a password manager to remember them. And use this event as an opportunity to change all your passwords to more secure ones.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler It is not uncommon to put the computer away for a while as-is so it can be used for looking for information that cannot be found elsewhere .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Refrain from keeping personal data or using personal online accounts on a work computer

> What would be the best course of action for me in order to keep my privacy?

Best course of action would be to remove all passwords and sensitive information from the computers/servers. Use secure delete command in the OS or use a 3rd party tool to render the deleted data unrecoverable. You don't need to *wipe hard drives* to do so.

You don't want to give any of your team members a misleading impression by stating that you need to wipe the hard drive. They may be afraid to lose any sensitive data, settings, app licenses etc. that may not be backed up or would require time taking configuration. State that you need to **remove some personal data** and **not wipe the hard drive**.

If you are not allowed access to computers or allowed to change anything, and the passwords correspond to your personal account, simply change them. Revoke any personal SSH keys deployed.

I have faced similar issues in past, and general advise I follow is to refrain from using **any** personal accounts or saving any personal data on work computers. I request IT to setup a company account for anything that I need.

---

Additionally, you may never know how the office network is configured. Your personal data from your computer/laptop/tables/smartphones may still be read/sniffed/logged if you access office network/Wi-Fi using them.

Always keep work and office data and equipments segregated and refrain from accessing work network/Wi-Fi from personal devices.

Comment: Securely delete the sensitive data?

Comment: @NMilev What OS are the work computers using? Generally you should be able to find a built in command or a 3rd party tool to securely wipe sensitive data.

Comment: I have the full access to the machines; I have set them up. Ny worry is that they will be able to restore some deleted data after I leave. It's not that they've done something to make me think that they will try to do something like this, I would just like to be super careful. I have not logged in any personal accounts but I have used a password that I use for some of my personal accounts.

Comment: One of the computers has Linux Ubuntu and the other one has Windows 10.

Comment: @NMilev I'd explain this situation to a higher up and seek assistance. At worse you may be required (personally or with help of IT) to setup the computer with OS install and environment setup. Basically make it usable.

Comment: I am not allowed to reinstall the os since it will delete some setting that they might find usable later on. It seems to me that the best thing is to try and delete as much as I can while changing all the personal passwords. And not to make this mistake again

Comment: I see such advice a lot, but there's a fairly large "grey area" here which few people seem to acknowledge. In most workplaces there exists a level of trust between employer and employee which makes accessing things like gmail, banking, social-media and news on a work machine a reasonable thing in moderation (with the exception of "secure facilities"). The vast majority of these things with passwords are web-applications where you can easily change passwords, use 2FA, or a password manager, and wipe browser history/cache to prevent casual poking around. Why aren't these actions "enough"?

Comment: I don't think the headline is practical advice. It's a very common practice to occasionally use a work computer for personal purposes (e.g., email, banking) which requires passing some sensitive personal information through the computer. It would be incredibly inconvenient to either have to take a second personal laptop to/from work for these tasks or to wait until after the workday to complete them.

Comment: @Jay Companies may tolerate some personal use for your company PC, but that doesn't mean you should be using it. You are at the mercy of the IT department wiping the PC when you leave. A smart company does that anyway, but you cannot count on it. If you are worried enough about people stealing passwords/data from your work PC, don't use it for personal business.

Comment: @Jay In 20 years of work history, I've literally never worked in an environment where it was considered OK to check personal email on company hardware. Besides the risk of your personal data being compromised, there's an obvious security risk to your employer (your employer can't control or filter your email for dangerous content). And on top of that, it's ironic that typical responses on workplace.SE about companies asking employees to work after hours are met with a strong "NEVER DO THAT" but people seem happy to suggest doing personal things on company time.

Comment: @dwizum, I have the exact opposite experience! It seems that there’s a wide variation in what’s considered acceptable/normal behavior with respect to usage of work computers.

Comment: @dwizum: In `$MANY` years of work history, I've never worked in an environment where it *wasn't* considered OK to check personal email on company hardware. At my most recent job, for example, the workstation on my desk was owned by the company, but nobody other than me had login access to it. (When I left the job, I deleted non-company related information and shut it down. I was told that the hard drive would be wiped later.) I understand my experience is not universal and might not be typical, especially for people other than software developers.

Answer (score 7):

**You should let your IT team handle your work computers - consider asking a colleague there if they can do a fresh install to overwrite the existing data.** If your company doesn't have an IT team or a vendor, talk with the individual responsible for managing the computers. Administrating equipment is usually not part of a developer's role, so you should ask those in the proper role to help you or defer to their judgement.

**Change your personal passwords elsewhere, and any passwords that are the same as those stored.** While you don't have control over your data on company equipment, you can take steps to keep yourself secure elsewhere. Change your GitHub/bank/etc. passwords and enable 2FA. You should be doing this regularly anyway.

In the future **consider a [password manager](https://1password.com/)** to store your personal information on a work computer in a way that is secure but also easily accessible to you. Of course, check with your firm's IT team to ensure the extra install is allowed.

Comment: As a developer I've said "I messed it up badly, it needs a fresh install." more than once.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, change all your passwords that may have been stored there as soon as possible.

And for the next time, do not keep any personal information on the work computer as you can be denied access to it at any time

Answer (score 1):

Only passwords? Not PII like DOB, SSN (or whatever personal id you use in your country)? If so, I would simply change the passwords on the sites I logged into. Gmail, banks, etc usually have 2 factor authentications. With gmail, I know you can revoke access to devices like your workstation and so forth. You can easily change the passwords and turn on 2 factor authentication. Then it wouldn't really matter if your password is visible on the work machines. As it wouldn't work and if it did, they'd have to enter the 2nd code to fully log in.